# Solving linear equation with some conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Consider the equation $y=af+bg+ch$ where $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c$ are between 0 and 1. y,f,g,h are  vectors with the same size and a,b and c are parameters that must be constant values. How can I solve the equation to find the value of a, b and c? Are there any software for this purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: If you know the vectors it's just a matter of row-reduction.

Comment: In general, you only need two rows of the vectors $y,f,g,h$ to solve these equations (unless the resulting reduced system is singular). You'd end up writing a couple of lines of code to solve a system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns. You may object that $a,b,c$ are constrained to $[0,1]$, but of course their values are (in general) uniquely determined by the linear equations even ignoring this constraint. Perhaps you want some type of "best" solution to a heavily overdetermined system?

Comment: @Zen Thanks for comment. yes, but I want some software to solve it quickly because the vectors are large.